# How can buoyant force be same in accelerating and non accelerating frame?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A block partially immersed in liquid in a container accelerating with acceleration 'a' upwards two observers watching it, one from ground frame and another  one from accelerating frame with acceleration 'a' upwards I don't understand how buoyant force can be equal in both frames... What I think is from accelerating frame 'a' net acceleration should be (g+a) i.e g effective and from ground frame g effective would be g... Where am I going wrong can someone point out and explain.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the block maintains it's shape, and does not crush or shrink with increased pressure, it's buoyancy will stay the same with upwards acceleration. It will float at the same level, whether accelerating upwards or not. As it's apparent weight increases with acceleration, so does the apparent weight of the water it displaces, so it's displacement is always the same. So both observers would see the block remain at the same level in the water.